# Preserve the modified date of a file during download

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I got feedback to preserve the modified date of downloaded file. I found a way to preserve it if I serve the file inside a zip, however got problem when I just serve the file as it is from my nodejs server.

Below is my current implementation :

```
  try{
    var stat = fs.statSync(fullpath);
    self.response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': mimeType,
         'Last-Modified': stat.mtime // not working
    });
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fullpath);
    fileStream.pipe(self.response);
    fileStream.on('end', function() {
      console.log("complete")
    });
  }catch(e)
  { //to handle user cancel the download and bring down whole system
    logger.error("streaming failed,because of:"+e.message);
  }
```

Initially I thought that setting the header 'Last-Modified' should do the trick but apparently it is not. Need to be able to work in Chrome, but if it works across browser, it would be great.

Note : It is not because of the format because using "Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT" instead of stat.mtime is not working as well.

**Update** : Seems impossible for browser right now as per early 2017, as shown in this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4574), the only way to do this is curl, or wget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the modified date on a file when the browser has downloaded and saved it?  You can't do that, as that would require operating system access on the remote computer.  The modified date on a file is a function of the filesystem on the client computer.

Comment: I suspected this is the case... but then I saw a firefox addon that able to save the date ...

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. Only older Firefox support this, and they eventually blocked the add-on. Will just accept your answer.

Comment: HTTP servers do like to send the modified date of a file (though when it's not a static file, it's up to the website author, and I suspect most don't bother fetching it ; often, they'll either not return a date at all, or return "now").